# Replace last character in sql column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data in table this way. If the ; is at the end I would like that replaced with a blank string if not I would leave data same way.

```
abc;
123;ghi;789
test123;
thisowns;
wer;567;457;test
```

Result should be

```
abc
123;ghi;789
test123
thisowns
wer;567;457;test
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE <YOUR_TABLE> 
SET col1 = LEFT(col1, LEN(col1) - 1)
WHERE RIGHT(col1, 1) = ';'
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select (case when col like '%;' then left(col, len(col) - 1) else col end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RIGHT()` function like

```
case when RIGHT(col1, 1) = ';' then LEFT(col1, LEN(col1) - 1) end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
;WITH cte_TestData (String)
AS
(
SELECT 'abc;' UNION ALL
SELECT '123;ghi;789' UNION ALL
SELECT 'test123;' UNION ALL
SELECT 'thisowns;' UNION ALL
SELECT 'wer;567;457;test'
)
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN RIGHT(String, 1) = ';'
            AND LEN(String) >= 1
            THEN SUBSTRING(String, 1, LEN(String) - 1)
        ELSE String
        END
FROM cte_TestData
```